# Angular.js, add string to name of variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This might be a dumb question, but I can't figure this out.
I have an array of objects with string values:

```
$scope.groups = [{name: "first"}, {name: "second"}];
```

And I have a bunch of items like this:

```
$scope.items = {first: [/*stuff*/], second: [/*stuff*/};
```

"first" and "second" are not explicitly defined, they are retrieved from server.
Is there any way to use `$scope.groups[0].name` as a part of `$scope.items.<here>`? Or perhaps there's a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript associative array syntax:

```
$scope.items[$scope.groups[0].name]
```

You can utilize this format to both get and set the value in `$scope.items`. You will, of course, need to at least initialize via `$scope.items = {};` before attempting this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define it as follows:

```
$scope.items[$scope.groups[0].name] = [/*stuff*/];
```